# SVN end of line characters using windows

Tags: svn, notepad++, commit, end-of-line

Lately I have used notepad++ a bit more than vim. However, when committing my work (done with notepad++) with a shell, the boring ^M windows end of line characters are appearing.
I guess notepad++ should have a setting to handle this.
Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this setting in Settings -> Preferences

[image]